# Save prime number to file

Tags: android, for-loop, textview, primes

I'm currently making an app that finds larger and larger prime numbers. When a new prime number is found, it will be saved to file. Only the last found prime need to be stored. The user should be able to view this prime. When the app starts, it will continue to look where it was when the app was closed.

But I have a problem with finding a way to save the prime number to file??

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button b;
    int max = 500;
    TextView vTextView;
    int j = 2;
    Button S;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        vTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);


        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                for (int i = j; i <= max; i++) {
                    if (isPrimeNumber(i)) {
                        vTextView.setText(i+"");
                        j = i+1;
                        break;

                    }
                }

            }
        });

    }

    public boolean isPrimeNumber(int number) {

        for (int i = 2; i <= number / 2; i++) {
            if (number % i == 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }


}
```

Comment: Hello. What about SharedPreferences instead of file ?

Comment: Nope. Have a look at this guide : https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files

Comment: You know what, I noticed that I can use SharedPreferences. What did u have in mind? @Bruno

Comment: see my detailed answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For write to file:**

```
public void writeToFile(String dataToWrite) {
    try {
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new
                File(getFilesDir() + File.separator + "MyFile.txt")));
        bufferedWriter.write(dataToWrite);
        bufferedWriter.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**For read from file:**

```
public String readFromFile() {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("");
    try {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new
                File(getFilesDir() + File.separator + "MyFile.txt")));
        String read;
        while ((read = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            builder.append(read);
        }
        bufferedReader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

Comment: Thank u, how do I implement it with my previous methods?

Comment: if (isPrimeNumber(i)) {
                        writeToFile(i+"");
                        vTextView.setText(i+"");
                        j = i+1;
                        break;

                    }

Comment: how do I read it? I want to make it read on the same buttonclick as the prime so when you first start the app and click on prime your last prime number will show and when you click again it should show the next number?

Answer (score 0):

If you can use `SharedPreferences`, you can do it like this:

- when you need to write a new file, read the value stored in SharedPreferences. If none, start à 0
- then, increase the retrieved value and used it
- after that, just store the new value in SharedPreferences

**How to read SharedPreferences**

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
int index = prefs.getInt("file_index", 0);
```

**How to write in SharedPreferences**

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
prefs.edit().putInt("file_index", index).commit();
```

Notice that it is better to create static Strings instead of using hardcoded one.

More details on SharedPreferences : https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences

Comment: I like this, but I really don't know how to implement it with my code. Right now it's not working.

Comment: Man...I gave you the code to write and to read in the SharedPreferences. Moreover, I pointed you the documentation...just give it a try and come back if you have more questions ;)